# Name is not defined for second chart Plotly Dash (Python)

Tags: python, plotly-dash

**1. I parse uploaded data and return df_con:
Result: OK**

```
def parse_data(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    global df_con
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV or TXT file
            df_con = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df_con = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        elif 'txt' or 'tsv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user upl, delimiter = r'\s+'oaded an excel file
            df_con = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')), delimiter = r'\s+')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return df_con
```

**2. Then create callback and make a Scatter.
Result: Chart is correct, but there is (minor) error “local variable ‘df_con’ referenced before assignment”.**

```
@app.callback(Output('graph3', 'figure'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
                Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_graph_upload(contents, filename):
    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df_con = parse_data(contents, filename)
    fig2 = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Scatter(
                x=df_con['datetime'], 
                y=df_con['fact'], 
                mode='lines+markers')
            ],
        layout=go.Layout(
            plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"]
        ))
    return fig2
```

**3. Create a function to analize uploaded data and return dfcnb
Result: Seems OK. (working on others script)**

```
def bal_costs_df(df_con):

    con = pyodbc.connect(
        'Driver={SQL Server};'
        'Server=HTIC--DB1.RF.RES;'
        'Database=EKX;'
        'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )

    df_con['plan'] = df_con['fact'].shift(168)
    querystringnp = f"""
        SELECT [ELSPOTP_LT_DATE_ID],
                  [ELSPOTP_LT_TIME_ID],
                  [ELSPOTP_PRICE]
        FROM [ET_DWH].[dbo].[FactElspotPrices]
        WHERE ELSPOTP_PAREA_ID = 1
        ORDER BY ELSPOTP_LT_DATE_ID
    """
    cursor = con.cursor()
    df_np = pd.read_sql(querystringnp, con) 
    
    #Many other data manipulation and return....
            
    return dfcnb
```

**4. Try to create another chart based on df_con and bal_costs_df function.
Result: Got error name ‘df_con’ is not defined.**

```
@app.callback(Output('graph4', 'figure'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
                Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_graph2(contents, filename):
    dfm = bal_costs_df(df_con)  <<<<<<<<<<<<ERROR: "name 'df_con' is not defined"
    fig3 = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Scatter(
                x=dfm['datetime'], 
                y=dfm['balcosts'], 
                mode='lines+markers')
            ],
        layout=go.Layout(
            plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"]
        ))
    return fig3
```

Any ideas why for graph3 is ok, but for graph4 df_con is not defined? Maybe inputs are wrong?
I want to have data as in dfcnb dataframe and create a chart from it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one problem. Any time this function runs with contents having a falsy value, you never define `df_con`. This will happen at least once, during initialization, when the callbacks fire with `None` input values.

```py
def update_graph_upload(contents, filename):
    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df_con = parse_data(contents, filename)
```

Given that you need `df_con`, and for that you need `contents`, I think it might be better to have

```py
if not contents:
    raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
contents = contents[0]
filename = filename[0]
df_con = parse_data(contents, filename)
```

In this last example:

```py
@app.callback(Output('graph4', 'figure'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
                Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_graph2(contents, filename):
    dfm = bal_costs_df(df_con)  <<<<<<<<<<<<ERROR: "name 'df_con' is not defined"
```

`df_con` isn't defined inside this function. I wouldn't recommend trying to use it as a global. If you want to pass data between callbacks, then I would suggest the [`dcc.Store` component](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store).

Comment: Thanks, based on your comment and additional effort I generated chart.

Comment: Glad to hear. It may be helpful to future viewers if you can include an explanation of what additional steps you took. Also, if this answer was helpful to you in solving the issue, please consider marking it as accepted.